# How to identify xpath that could be child of iframe

Tags: html, xpath

I am new to automation, currently learning online on my own. I was wondering if anyone would help me identify the xpath for the checkbox on this domo https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: So just to be clear - you're looking for a way to automate the "I'm not a robot" checkbox? Like... via some kind of bot?

Comment: I was trying to find the element on the iframe, has nothing to do with internet bot.

Answer (score 0):

The checkBox on the demo is inside the iframe. To interact with the checkbox, you need to navigate into the frame with below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

then, you can use one of the below xpath to ineract with it:

```
//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']
```

or

```
//*[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']
```

or

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation Tejas. It was very helpful and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way would be to identify the exact iframe you need and then switch to it:

```
WebElement frameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='recaptcha-demo']//iframe)); // find the exact iframe element and save reference to it
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement); // switch context to required frame
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']") // click checkbox
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // to switch context back to initial document
```

The order or number of frames may differ, so this approach makes sure you have the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your input with detailed code example Kudin!

Comment: no problem, you might want to consider accepting one of the responses as accepted solution